# XSLT dynamic xpath child selection

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I need to select childs recursively by a given path.
This is my XML structure:

```
<items>
   <item name="first">
      <item name="fist-first">
         [...]
      </item>
      <item name="first-second">
         [...]
      </item>
      [...]
   </item>
</items>
```

I need to select a specific item by path (like "0-1" to select the second child of the first element) passed by xsl:param. I have a string representing the actual node path concerning their child position.

Does anybody know if this is possible and give me some help?

I use saxon 9.8he.

Thanks in advance

Comment: So which XSLT processor, which XSLT version can you use? Some provide dynamic XPath evaluation. In that case you would need to pass in standard XPath syntax of course like `/items/item[1]/item[2]`, not some other syntax.

Comment: `"0-1"` is not a path. Show us exactly what your parameter looks like - and state which processor will you be using.

Comment: Sorry, I use saxon 9.8he. The "path" only consists of the corresponding child number, but it would okay using an XPath string like "/items/item[1]/item[2]", if I can pass it as string param. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First turn `$path` into a sequence of positive integers, such as (1,4,6), using the `tokenize()` function, and then call this recursive function:

```
<xsl:function name="f:by-path" as="element()?">
 <xsl:param name="origin" as="element()*"/>
 <xsl:param name="path" as="xs:integer*"/>
 <xsl:sequence select="
     if (empty($path)) 
     then $origin 
     else $origin[head($path)]/f:by-path(*, tail($path))"/>
</xsl:function>
```

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

With Saxon 9.8 and XSLT 3.0 you could use a [static parameter](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#dt-static-parameter) with the path expression

```
<xsl:param name="path" static="yes" as="xs:string" select="'/items/item[1]/item[2]'"/>
```

and where you want to use that path you would not use a normal `select` attribute but the corresponding [shadow attribute](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#shadow-attributes) `_select="{$path}"` instead e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:copy-of _select="{$path}"/>
</xsl:template>
```

You can then set that parameter when you run the stylesheet like any other parameters.